# using rspec to test a controller in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Does anyone know how to test a controller of gem in the app using the gem with rspec? I have tried http://codingdaily.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/test-a-gem-with-the-rails-3-stack/ and http://say26.com/rspec-testing-controllers-outside-of-a-rails-application without success.

I have a controller in a gem like this:

```
module mygem
 class PostsController < ::ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Posts.find(:all)
    @other_var = 10        
  end
 end
end
```

And I would like to have a test in my app like spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb

```
describe PostsController do
  describe "index" do

    it "has posts" do
      get :index
      assigns(:posts).should_not be_nil
    end

    it "has other var" do
      get :index
      assert_equal(10, assigns(:other_var))
    end

  end
end
```

And my spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)    
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

end
```

I know rspec isn't really meant for this, and ideas or alternatives would be helpful too.

Comment: Have you tried the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12499404/306084)?

Comment: I don't have paths to the gem controllers like that in my app.

Comment: Have you looked into making your gem a Rails Engine? Sounds like it would be a better fit since generally gems don't include controllers. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 0):

A gem is a gem, an app is an app. They are different stuff.

I don't think it's a good practice to mix testing of gem into the app.

Normally you don't need to test a gem because they are usually well tested. If you really want to do that or the gem is lack of test, fork the gem and pull it in local, then open its test files and add yours. Then you can push it back to improve this gem or end up your own version of gem.

If you are writing your own gem, put the tests in gem but not app.

If you want to test some functionalities the gem added to your app, you can test the integrated effect, but don't need unit testing.

Comment: I agree with this, one problem though is the app has initializers and settings the gem will need to function and so I can't test the gem completely by itself, and also my boss won't let me do it that way, which is really the proper way. ha.

Comment: No, you can. A gem must be separated from app otherwise it's not a gem but part of app. If this is your gem and it needs an app to test, you can create a demo app within the gem.

Comment: What if you want to test certain features? say i have devise_token_auth and i test if my model works properly with it.

Comment: @BillyChan by any chance do you know of any gems out there that have a demo app within them? My gem requires a developer to update ActiveModels, Controllers, and views so I would have to test rails functionality within my gem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel dumb now, I just had to add the gem namespace to the controllers. so

```
describe PostsController do
...
end
```

becomes

```
describe mygem::PostsController do
...
end
```